# Python: Trying to form string from instance methods

Tags: python, class, error-handling

I am trying to form an string from two class methods. However, I get an

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instancemethod' and 'instancemethod'
```

error with the following code:

```
class Root():

    def header(self):
        return '''<html>
                  <body>'''

    def footer(self):
        return '''</body>
                  </html>'''


a_root = Root()
a_string = a_root.header + a_root.footer
print(a_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the methods and thus require `()` to call

```
class Root():

    def header(self):
        return '''<html>
                  <body>'''

    def footer(self):
        return '''</body>
                  </html>'''


a_root = Root()
a_string = a_root.header() + a_root.footer()
print(a_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the parenthesis:

```
a_string = a_root.header() + a_root.footer()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call those methods:

```
# There is no need to have 'Root()' if you aren't inheriting
class Root:

    def header(self):
        return '''<html>
                  <body>'''

    def footer(self):
        return '''</body>
                  </html>'''


a_root = Root()
# Call the methods by adding '()' to them
a_string = a_root.header() + a_root.footer()
print(a_string)
```